# Charset Problem while migrating database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, character-encoding, migration

I have a custom made CMS that I must migrate to work on Wordpress. Everything worked fine except the charset module.

Since this is about a Rumanian blog content, there are some special chars used (this will be ă, î, ș, â, Ț). When i insert this content on wordpress wp_posts, Wordpress displays them as "?".

I've tried all kind of stuff, like changing the charset from utf8 to latin1, latin2, and so on, but no result.

Even more, when i try to replace that special characters with normal ones (eg: ă to a, î to i) nothing happens, the content remains the same (there are actually some chars that are changed but not all)

What i do wrong and what i must do to do it right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Character sets are a complete nightmare. What I'd do is to use mysqldump to dump your database to a sql file. Check to see if the special chars still look right.

Then, using find and replace in a text editor, replace all special characters with the correct html entity. e.g. Ă becomes &#x102;.

http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Romanian_characters

Then delete your database, set all conceivable settings to utf-8, and import your dump.

Wordpress also has an [extensive article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets) about character encodings.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, find and replace with Notepad++ solved the problem :)